# Call other feature files from Karate test with multiple tag selectors

Tags: karate

Is it possible to specify more than one tag selector when calling other feature files?

https://github.com/intuit/karate#call-tag-selector

Example: **call read('classpath:my-signin.feature@br@e2e')**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Calling is meant only for re-using common code and to be used sparingly. Note that you can use `karate.call()` to programmatically make a call, so this is not a limitation.

Comment: Got it. I was more curious about it. I am going to end up creating a specific tag that points to the exact scenario I want to run. Thanks!